# Unable to understand query after where clause in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a javaFX application with postgresql as a database , I go through the code . But unable to understand sql query in where clause. here is sql query.

```
SELECT *
FROM gr_group
WHERE gr_parent_id = ? AND gr_id <> 0
ORDER BY gr_description
```

Comment: This looks like a normal query set up for parameterization.  What exactly don't you understand?  The only thing I see wrong with it is that the developer decided to use `SELECT *`.

Comment: @BaconBits I was unable to understand   <> this symbol in queries

Comment: `<>` is "not equal" in SQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a parametrized SQL query.  The question mark `?` you see in the `WHERE` clause will be filled with an actual parameter coming from a Java variable.

Answer (score 0):

<> (Not Equal To) is an operator. It is same as != operator.

This query will select all the columns from the table gr_group where gr_id is not equal to 0 and gr_parent_id specifies a place holder which will be filled later in the code. This query also orders selected data in the ascending order of column gr_description.